# QTWebKit build error on Windows

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebkit

I have QT 5.3 and an application that use a QWebView widget. But I have a PC that doesn't have SSE2 (that is requiered for QT 5.3), so I decided to build QT from source without SSE2 to run my application on this PC. QT compiled without problem but when I want to compile the QTWebKit module there is an error :

```
(...)-LC:/qt-5.3.0/qtbase/lib -lQt5Positioning -LC:/qt-5.3.0/qtbase/lib -lQt5Sensors -LC:/qt-5.3.0/qtbase/lib -lQt5Core
Warning: resolving _cti_vm_throw by linking to @cti_vm_throw@4
Use --enable-stdcall-fixup to disable these warnings
Use --disable-stdcall-fixup to disable these fixups
C:/qt-5.3.0/qtwebkit/WebKitBuild/Release/Source/WebKit2/release/libWebKit2.a(QtNetworkAccessManager.o):QtNetworkAccessManager.cpp:(.text+0x310): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN13QNetworkReply15ignoreSslErrorsERK5QListI9QSslErrorE'
C:/qt-5.3.0/qtwebkit/WebKitBuild/Release/Source/WebKit2/release/libWebKit2.a(QtNetworkAccessManager.o):QtNetworkAccessManager.cpp:(.text$_ZN5QListI9QSslErrorED1 Ev[__ZN5QListI9QSslErrorED1Ev]+0x14): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN9QSslErrorD1Ev'
C:/Qt/Tools/mingw482_32/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.8.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/qt-5.3.0/qtwebkit/WebKitBuild/Release/Source/WebKit2/release/libWebKit2.a(QtNetworkAccessManager.o): bad reloc address 0x14 in section `.text$_ZN5QListI9QSslErrorED1Ev[__ZN5QListI9QSslErrorED1Ev]'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I suppose it is due to

```
Warning: resolving _cti_vm_throw by linking to @cti_vm_throw@4
```

I also thought about a bug in webkit but I'm not sure.

Could you help me to resolve this ?

Comment: Do you have Qt (network module) built with ssl support? If not, build that yourself. Also, please read the [tag:qt] tagwiki.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I checked with configure and it appears that OpenSSL support is "yes".

Comment: Are you trying to build release against the release QtNetwork 5.3 dll? Can you check if the qtnetwork dll has those symbols? By the way, your error is the undefined references, definitely not the warning.

Comment: hmm i don't know. I just have the debug and release QtNetwork 5.3 dll. (and I ran this script to build QtWebKit : "perl Tools\Scripts\build-webkit --qt --release")

Comment: It seems that I don't have these symbols. I only have 'ZN13QNetworkReply15ignoreSslErrorsEv' in debug QNetwork dll, but nothing in the release dll. Do I have to re-build QT ?

Comment: I wonder how you got so different release and debug builds. How did you obtain them?

Comment: I just built source with mingw32-make to obtain these dll.

Comment: Have you passed -openssl to configure both times? Perhaps, you forgot that for the release? I would advise you rebuild the release dll again with that option enabled.

Comment: No I don't passed -openssl but when i check with configure it is marked as "yes".

Comment: have you installed openssl properly before building the release dll, or only after?

Comment: I installed it during the compilation so maybe after the release dll was compiled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error seems to be about not found symbols in your QtNetwork release dll file. The reason is that you built that module without OpenSSL support.

> C:/qt-5.3.0/qtwebkit/WebKitBuild/Release/Source/WebKit2/release/libWebKit2.a(QtNetworkAccessManager.o):QtNetworkAccessManager.cpp:(.text+0x310): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN13QNetworkReply15ignoreSslErrorsERK5QListI9QSslErrorE'
>
> C:/qt-5.3.0/qtwebkit/WebKitBuild/Release/Source/WebKit2/release/libWebKit2.a(QtNetworkAccessManager.o):QtNetworkAccessManager.cpp:(.text$_ZN5QListI9QSslErrorED1 Ev[__ZN5QListI9QSslErrorED1Ev]+0x14): undefined reference to `_imp___ZN9QSslErrorD1Ev'

Based on the comment discussion, it seems that you have only installed OpenSSL properly during the compilation of your release QtNetwork module build. That is very likely the reason for this issue.

The solution is to rebuilt your qtnetwork release build as your system is now, so you will get the SSL related symbols in your dll.

Remember that the criteria is that you need to have a proper openssl installation that Qt can recognize while trying to build.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But now, when i try to rebuilt QT with OpenSSL (gnuwin32), It give me a lot of errors when QRegularexpression compile.